# Selenium compatability with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am able to run the script successfully on Firefox and i am not able to run the same script on Chrome. Please help me in finding these issue.

Thanks

Comment: please provide code used to start the chrome and also exception

Comment: Yes it's happend but you need to show/tell us what exactly is not working in crome .. like click event etc

Answer (score 1):

Hi to run test in chrome please call chrome driver like below

```
// call the Chrome driver as below first 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\eclipseProject\\##\\src\\com\\##\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
// path to chrome exe that you have downloaded form given url (below)
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.com"); // link to your web-table web page
```

now your script as same on firfox

// download chrome exe form this link http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/